# Publish multiple Azure functions without overwriting each other's dll's

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have 3 Azure functions using .NET Core 3.1 in 3 different solutions. Each solution has a project with its own `host.json`, Startup and function trigger file and also contains several dependent projects based on NETStandard Library.

I am publishing all the 3 functions to one AppService. When I do this, I can see that in Kudu, there is only 1 host.json and 1 bin folder created. I am forcing all 3 host.json files to be same and has all dependencies but the problem is that the version of dll's for the same dll file in the /bin folder are getting overwritten by the last published function.

Is there a way for me to have separate /bin folder at `/home/site/wwwroot/` for each function?

Comment: Because you are deploying  a whole function app, that is why it will overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your understanding of azure function app and triggers.

[image]

When you deploy azure functions, basicaly every time it is deploy azure function app. So this is why it overwritten.

**You should create function in function app like this(if you are using Vistual Studio):**

[image]

**If you are using function core tools with other develop tools, then:**

create function app:

```
func init
```

create new function(trigger):

```
func new
```

Comment: No, I am __publishing__ individual functions from Visual studio to the same function app.

Comment: I have unchecked remove additional files at destination, so when a new function is published it updates the common files and the older functions has a mismatch - thats the issue I am facing

Comment: Individual functions? You mean individual function app?

Comment: No, I mean individual __function__ - I am able to do so because each function is a separate project in VS

Comment: @NandiniSinghal I think you dont understand my explanation. "separate function project in VS" in your description = a function app. Basically, when you deploy from local, no matter you are using VS or func core tools, function app will be deployed from the compilated files. (If you are using C# or Java,then you need to deploy compiled files, simple script function app dont need to deploy compiled files.)

Comment: @NandiniSinghal You say deploy from three project, ok...I will explain again, these is three "function apps". The deployment of azure function is not an incremental deployment, so it is expected that the deployment file you deploy now will overwrite the previous. This is how it is designed.

Comment: @NandiniSinghal Your azure function development method has problem. If in the way of you are try to doing now, then you need to integrate compiled files from three different function project manually. And, this way is nothing different from develop three function in one project and deploy.

Comment: @NandiniSinghal To repeat, the deployment of function app is not incremental.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft doesn't want you to avoid buying more than one container, but if you are low on fund or in a rush you can try this:

Suppose you have 2 function called MyFunction1 and MyFunction2

1. Publish your function in a folder.
2. Go inside the folder.
3. Rename the folder Bin in something like BinMyFunction1
4. Inside the folder called MyFunction there is a file called function.json, edit the path to the bin to your new renamed bin

[example of function.json edit:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeF0R.jpg)

Optional: repeat for MyFunction2

[In the end merge everything in a folder, it should look like that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeNPW.jpg)

More likely you can pick one of the host.json, but it really depends what you want to achieve.
Just in case you have to define manually your host.json:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json

Zip everything and pass to kudu deploy.

Comment: can you share the reference to this?

Comment: I have no reference i just try it out and it worked.

Comment: mmm I realize that my solution doesn't solve the problem at all. They still share the same bin folder. In our working environment we upgrade all the project so if they share a library they will have the same version. For the project dll we have something like myproject1.dll myproject2.dll so they don't get overwritten.
Although have 2 project share the same container means that 2 team can work in parallel on 2 different project and deploy it on the same container.

Comment: Ok I mess around a little bit with the configuration and I'm ready to give the correct answer. I will edit my answer