# Incrementally add function to Azure Function Host without overwriting already deployed functions

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-deployment

I'm working with multiple teams that develop & test Azure Functions independently from each other but want to deploy all functions to a centralized Azure Function host, like so:
[image: Deployment pipeline]

The publishing methods I know overwrite the existing content on the host which is not wanted, we strive for an **incremental update** (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468905/publish-multiple-azure-functions-without-overwriting-each-others-dlls) question with the only difference that we use Python on Linux-based host instead of C#).

My question is: What is the easiest way to do this (assuming that hosts.json and function settings are the same for both projects)?

If team A runs

```
curl -X POST -u <user> --data-binary @"./func1-2.zip" https://<funcname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy
```

in their release pipeline and afterwards team B runs

```
curl -X POST -u <user> --data-binary @"./func3-4.zip" https://<funcname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy
```

func1 and func2 from team A are gone. Using PUT on the `https://<funcname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/` endpoint as indicated [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#zip) didn't seem to publish the functions at all. When using FTP, I don't see any files in site/wwwroot/ at all, even after already publishing functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use continuous deployment:

First, create a repo on Github, then configure deploy center:

[image]

Then use git to upload your local function app to Github:

```
echo "# xxxxxx" >> README.md
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin <git-url>
git push -u origin main
```

update:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "something"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin <git-url>
git push -u origin main
```

Refer to this official doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment

Comment: But that would mean I have a centralized Git repository. That's not wanted in my case, each team should only have their own repository.

Comment: @SimonNobel In your case, I think there is no good way to achieve incremental deployment. Most deployment method you can find will overwrite the original project. Continuous deployment is incremental, but continuous deployment does not support multiple repo, and the linux-based function app cannot modify the project by directly uploading files. So, unfortunately there is no way to do it.